# Spring WebFluxTest add Pageable resolver

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-test, spring-webclient

I want to test my Spring controller using `@WebFluxTest(MyController.class)`

My test :

```java
@WebFluxTest({MyController.class})
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient client;

    @Test
    void myTest() {
            List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3);
            Page<Integer> expected = new PageImpl<>(list);
            String buCode = TestUtils.getRandomString();

            when(myService.method(
                    any(), // Pageable
                    anyString()
            )).thenReturn(Mono.just(expected));

            client.get()
                    .uri("/path?arg=test")
                    .exchange()
                    .expectStatus()
                    .isOk();
        }
}
```

My controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("path")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping
    Mono<Page<Integer>> searchSeller(
            Pageable pageable, 
            @RequestParam(required = false) String arg
    ) {
        return myService.search(pageable, arg);
    }
}
```

But I have this exception when I execute my test :

```
No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable
```

I think the solution is maybe to register the `org.springframework.data.web.ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but I don't know how to register it into the `WebTestClient`

Have you some clues to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class PageableWebFluxConfiguration implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    
    private static final String PAGE_PARAM_NAME = "page";
    private static final String SIZE_PARAM_NAME = "perPage";

    @Override
    public void configureArgumentResolvers(ArgumentResolverConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.addCustomResolver(pageableHandler());
    }
    
    private ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandler() {
         ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableHandler = new ReactivePageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
         pageableHandler.setPageParameterName(PAGE_PARAM_NAME);
         pageableHandler.setSizeParameterName(SIZE_PARAM_NAME);
         return pageableHandler;
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).